# content overlapping in different bootstrap section

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm making bootstrap skeleton for a WordPress site on top most header section I had video background which is working fine when I added another section content from that section overlapping to header section 
my site looks like

[image]

my code looks like

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box !important;
}

body {
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
}


/* ======================= Header ======================== */

#background {
    position: fixed;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    min-width: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
    z-index: -100;
    -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
    transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
    background-size: cover;
}

video {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: -1;
    opacity: 0.78;
}

.header .text-contant {
    margin-top: 40%;
}

.header .text-contant h1,
.header .text-contant p{
    color: #fff;
}

.header .text-contant h1 {
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-family: 'Sansita', sans-serif;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.header .text-contant p {
    letter-spacing: 1px;
}

.header .text-contant i {
    padding-top: 33px;
    color: #fff;
}

@media(max-width:992px) {
    .header .text-contant {
    margin-top: 50%;
}
}

@media(max-width:768px) {
    .header .text-contant {
    text-align: center;
}
}

@media(max-width:480px) {
    .header .text-contant {
    margin-top: 80%;
}
}

@media(max-width:320px) {
    .header .text-contant {
    margin-top: 100%;
}
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <!-- The above 3 meta tags *must* come first in the head; any other head content must come *after* these tags -->
    <title>Bootstrap Boilerplate</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <link href="/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto|Sansita:400,700" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/style.css">

    <!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js for IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.3/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
</head>

<body>

    <!-- ===================== HEADER ============================= -->


    
        <section class="header">
        <video autoplay loop muted poster="/img/pexels-photo-27884.jpg" id="background">
            <source src="/vdo/River%20-%206815.mp4" type="video/mp4">
        </video>
        <div class="container text-contant">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-8">
                    <h1>My WordPress</h1>
                    <p>Just Another WordPress Theme</p>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-3 col-sm-offset-1">
                    <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-chevron-circle-down fa-4x" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
    
    
    <!-- ===================== MAIN ============================= -->
   
    
    <section id="article">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-8">
                <article class="blog">
                    <div class="blog-meta-detail">
                        <i class="fa fa-clock-o" aria-hidden="true"> February 17 2017 </i>
                        <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-user" aria-hidden="true"> cannelflow</i></a>
                        
                        <i class="fa fa-folder" aria-hidden="true"> Music,Tech</i>
                        <i class="fa fa-tags" aria-hidden="true"> Tag 1,Tag 2</i>
                    </div>
                    <div class="blog-title">
                        <h2>Sample Blog Post 1</h2>
                    </div>
                </article>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <aside class="sidebar"></aside>
            </div>
        </div>
        </div>
    </section>
    

    <!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
    <script src="/js/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed -->
    <script src="/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/js/main.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

thanks in advance

Comment: ceontent, not contant

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to use a fixed height for the video, using media queries to change the video height as you reduce the windows width (for mobile and tablets websites). Then the best way to position the html over the video is using flexbox. For cropping the video you can user margin-top : <0px;

You code is too complicated and I can not fix it, you should have posted an example of your problem and then we could help.